# What are the odds of getting an evolution item from a PokéStop?

Tags: pokemon-go

Thanks to [another question on this site](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300801/how-do-i-get-evolution-items-like-kings-rock), I know that I can obtain the new items required for the new evolutions from PokéStops. My question is, how common are these items? I've spun about a dozen stops and not seen a single one yet. Most PokéStop items are more common than that, so I'm wondering if they are pretty rare, or if I've just been unlucky.

Comment: I'm on the app and haven't figured out a way to get the url for questions with it, or I would post s link to the related question.

Comment: Would [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/300801/how-do-i-get-evolution-items-like-kings-rock?rq=1) be the URL you wanted? :)

Comment: While I don't have any concrete data (hence not posting as an answer), I've been spinning for almost the whole day and have got one Sun Stone. So.. it seems they are _quite_ a lot rarer than other Poke Stop items!

Comment: Empirically ~1:500 items from pokestop (i have three of them, from about 1700 items)

Comment: @KevinL how exactly did you get 1700 Pokéstop items since the release 16 hours prior to your comment?

Comment: @KevinL wow! Have you been doing nothing but visiting stops since the update? You should expand that into an answer; it's a big enough sample size to be meaningful, and I doubt anyone can top it at this point.

Comment: @Kat would you consider a bunch of people's estimates on how long it took to find their first evolutionary item (or how many they have spun so far without getting one) a feasible answer?

Comment: @Venomous If you have a big enough sample size, sure. It will probably be a bit biased towards the lucky people, but it'll give us a general idea, at least. Based on Kevin's comment, you're probably going to need at least a thousand stops worth of data to get good results.

Comment: @Vemonus I live in an area where you can hit about 50 pokestops in 5 min slowly riding a bike. So at ~600 stops an hour, i spent maybe an hour and a half this morning biking around and catching things.

Comment: @Kat I don't think that my sample size is large enough to make any concrete statements, although feel free to add it into an aggregate sample

Comment: @Venomous you can put me down for 19 stops with nada.

Comment: @KevinL if you don't mind saying, what city are you in? I live near Portland, which I've heard is one of the best places to play, and I don't think I could manage anywhere near 50 in five minutes.

Comment: @Kat The specific location where I go for [pokestops](http://imgur.com/a/E5LFk) is [Lake View Cemetery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_View_Cemetery)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl;dr**: While no concrete numbers have been confirmed yet, the odds of finding one from a PokéStop are *very slim*. Based on the reports I've been reading, it looks like the odds to receive one are at or around 1%, possibly lower. In fact, from [this report](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/gen-2-pokestop-item-drops-berries-evolution-items-changed/), the calculated probability of receiving an evolutionary item seems to be roughly 0.14%, as a grand total of 33 evolutionary items were received among over 24,000 drops.

**However**, it's worth noting that it seems like you are **now *guaranteed* to get an evolutionary item when spinning your 7th day streak PokéStop**, according to this in-game notification:

[image: notification]

---

Until this update has been around for longer, it's not possible to have the most accurate numbers in terms of the probability of these items appearing from PokéStops, but numerous users have been reporting that they received an evolutionary item as a daily streak bonus reward (especially so for 7th day Streak bonuses).

For instance, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5unkzh/probably_coincidence_but_i_got_my_first_and_only/):

> Probably coincidence, but I got my first and only evolution item from my 7-day streak Pokestop spin. 100+ spins before that came up empty.
>
> I got one last night. But also got one on my 7-day streak this morning.
>
> Got a metal coat from 7 day spin

One comment linked to [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5umf9u/22_items_on_my_7th_day_spin_king_stone_included/) which originally speculated that these items *only* came from 7th day streak spins (this has since been disproven numerous times, though it has now been confirmed that you are guaranteed an evolutionary item for this):

> I got my Sun Stone on my 7 day spin this morning too. Havent found an evo item since. Increased chance on 7 day streak spins? Or just plain luck?
>
> I got an upgrade with my 7 day streak this morning. It may be that we're guaranteed an evolution item at each 7 day streak but you can also get them randomly at pokestops.
>
> I also got my sunstone today at my 7th day streak. My friend got a dragonscale in his first spin of the day( normal streak).
>
> 7th day spin for me this morning too, I got an Up-Grade
>
> I just spun for my 7th day streak - got Upgrade. Prior to that, I had to spin pokestops for almost 8 hours before I received a King's Rock.

As many have noted, however, you are able to get these items randomly from PokéStops. Some users in that thread also estimated how many spins it took them to find their first evolutionary item. From that thread:

> I spun over 400 yesterday to get my first sun stone. this took 5 hours of downtown grinding.
>
> I spun over 100 today as well as yesterday and nothing so far. Not even for my 6 day spin.
>
> About 250 spins today, got a Sun Stone from a random spin.
>
> Meanwhile I'm on spin 175 for today and still not a single evolution item.

Users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uo29b/number_of_pokestops_spun_until_your_first/#bottom-comments) have also been reporting how many spins it took them to find their first evolutionary item (or not):

> 300 for me, none yet.
>
> 100~ got 1 King's Rock
>
> 200+ nothing. I did get a king stone from my 7 day streak reward.
>
> Within my first 4 in the way to the station this morning, i received a Sun stone. Nothing since.

A [fourth thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5umb54/evolution_items_drop_rate_initial_research_queries/) has been aggregating data to try to figure out the drop rates for the new items as well.

> 13 nanab berries and 6 pinap berries from probably 200 pokestop spins. No evolution items.
>
> Got an upgrade after maybe 50 odd spins?
>
> None after +100 spins
>
> I received a dragon scale this morning on my 7th day streak pokestop. In the U.K. near Reading.
>
> My son got Up-grade on first spin of the day today (not 7-day). Maryland, USA.
>
> Spun roughly 500 Pokestops since Gen2 launched. Zero evolution items thus far but the drop rate on Pinap/Nanab is fairly good.

There are other threads like these, like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5uny5d/just_to_further_describe_how_rare_evolutionary/) or [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/5ukp6h/how_rare_are_evolution_items_at_pokestops/).

---

In addition to all of these reports, from the comments above:

- @KevinL reports 3 evolutionary items out of roughly 1700 items (roughly 425-450 spins (estimating 40 items per 10 spins))
- @Kat reports 0 evolutionary items from 19 stops
- @TimMalone reports 1 evolutionary item over the course of an entire day's PokéStop spins

Additionally, I have received 0 evolutionary items from about 10 spins since they became available.

Comment: That rare, uh? I ended up being then lucky for getting an "upgrade" on my first PokéStop

Comment: @Wondercricket some people appear to be having better luck than others, but most people have gotten very few, if any.

Comment: @Wondercricket was it a seven day streak? Venomous, great research, as always. You mentioned speculation that you're guaranteed an item on your seven day streak spin. Did you see anyone say they'd *not* gotten one on their seventh day streak spin?

Comment: @Kat oh yeah, even in some of those threads, there were a few people who did not get them as streak rewards, so it's definitely not guaranteed, though it seems like higher chances than just a regular spin. (also, minor note: my username is Vemonus -- misspelled on purpose, though due to how much confusion it's caused, I've considered changing it...)

Comment: @Kat oh, also, my 7th day streak is coming up, so I can update this when I spin it. I'll also be on the lookout for more concrete numbers as more people are able to gather evidence and crunch numbers.

Comment: ...Wow, I really should've noticed I've been misspelling your name much sooner. Sorry! How embarrassing. Anyway, my seven day streak is coming up too, so I'll let you know if I get anything.

Comment: @Kat on my 7th day spin, I got an Up-Grade (the only item I can't use). Seems like it *is* more likely on that day.

Comment: I got a metal coat on my seven day streak spin. Definitely a massively increased chance, I'd say.

Comment: Friday was also my 7th day streak and I've got one King's Rock from it and also a Dragon Scale from my first night walk around in a huge park in the city center. My guess is that the Dragon Scale was like a gift for the early birds :)

Comment: [more research](https://pokemongohub.net/generation-2/gen-2-pokestop-item-drops-berries-evolution-items-changed/). Most important conclusion is that drop rate of evolve items was _extremely_ high on the first day of launch (feb 16) and evidence suggests it was dialed back sometime on feb 17. Actual drop rate as of 2/23/2017 may be under 0.3% chance of a evo item per stop

Comment: @KevinL good find, I'll update this answer after work with the evidence you've found. The 0.3% is abysmal, though :(

Comment: Apparently that data includes streaks, which means it's even worse than that for random stops. :( I guess I got really lucky when I got a kings rock the other day.

Comment: @Kat ugh. I didn't get an item for my 7th day streak this week, either, just an FYI...

Answer (score 5):

As of this afternoon (March 22nd), I'm seeing a news item when I log in which says the 7-day streak first PokeStop is guaranteed to drop an evolution item. This seems to be a change, because my last few 7-day streaks did not give an evolution item.

As the other answers show, the drop rate outside the 7-day streak is really, really low.

Comment: This is confirmed on Niantic's [support](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/ver-update-032117) page